# Linux emulate multiple Wifi connections

Tags: wifi, wlan, interface

I have a Linux machine that creates a Wifi hotspot. I need to simulate a few clients connecting to that hotspot and then using that connectiong to talk to a service, through the wlan interface. The service is running in it's own process and the clients would be connecting from another process. Is there a way to achieve this? Something like create another interface on the same subnet as the wlan? Thanks

Comment: Tell us why you want to simulate them.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro We want to test that some thrift clients connecting through Wifi to the machine would work accordingly. Basically to test that tls/ssl is connecting ok...

Comment: We are getting somewhere. Testing FreeRadius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `mac80211_hwsim` kernel module. This module simulates a number of virtual "radios" (wifi cards, or `phy`s) that communicate with each other. E.g.,

```
modprobe mac80211_hwsim radios=3
```

will give you 3 of those. Use `iw dev` to view them and see their MAC address. Then you can use `iw` and `ip` to configure them, and simulate an access point and as many clients as you want. You'll also get a `hwsim0` interface of `ieee802.11/radiotap` type, and you can run `wireshark` on it to see the messages that go through the "virtual" air.

If the software you are using on the wireless network interfaces can't bind to specific interfaces, consider putting it into a network namespace for each client.